# C++: Replacement for Singleton

Tags: c++, class, singleton

I use singletons a lot because I hate to pass an object of the main class to member classes in order to allow them to access the main class.

```
Class Foo
{
    A* a;
    B* b;
    C* c;
};
```

For example in the above example if A,B and C would like to access Foo- I would have to pass the object of Foo each one of them, and store it as their member variable (or give the object in every function call). This works, but it does not feel right and requires more code writing.

Instead, I can make Foo a singleton (of course only if there can be only 1 instance) and then just call Foo::getInstance()->... from A, B and C. And I do not have to pass any objects. I find this very handy.

Now, the problem is that I have a situation where there can be multiple instances of Foo. Obviously I cannot use singleton pattern. But I do not want to pass variables nor store them in member classes. Too much code! :)

As an example,
I hate this:

```
A::A(Foo* foo) : m_foo(foo)
{

}
```

and this:

```
void A::someFunc(Foo* foo, int someParam)
{

}
```

But, I love this:

```
A::A()
{

}

void A::someFunc(int someParam)
{
    Foo* foo = Foo::getInstance();
}
```

Is there any other way to do it? Something that resembles the singleton pattern?

Comment: I don't understand why you're even using singletons in C++ in the first place.

Comment: Because I can access the object globally everywhere without any kind of passing. It's easy.

Comment: @ptrdiff_t What's the actual problem you're trying to solve, here?  It doesn't make sense to me that you want something to look like a singleton but still have multiple instances.  Posting the "inconvenient" code will help give me a better idea of what you want to avoid.

Comment: Using singletons might seem good at first glance but in fact they make your code worse:
- They make you code much less clear (code depends on context in an implicit way)
- They make the code hard to test
- They make the code hard to maintain, mostly because of future changes
It might work for small examples, but big projects should avoid singletons when possible.

Comment: Arggg. Stop. Stop. Stop. Go read a book about programming or take a course on programming. What seems to make things easy now just makes all other parts of programming impossibly hard. Stop it. Remember the maintainer of your code knows where you live **and** he owns an axe.

Comment: I suspect that a few 24 hour marathon debugging sessions resulting from using globals/singletons that have their state mutated in an unexpected way may change your view on their usefulness.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This kind of pattern is creating a bunch of circular references, which in general is a code smell. You may want to take a solid look at your design, because the usual way to solve these sort of relationship problems is to create a third class that interacts with both existing classes. Alternately, what wrong with passing along a reference to the containing class if you really need that behavior?

Comment: There's actually nothing wrong - I am just lazy. But seems like I have to do it...

And yes, that's a code smell definitely but happens very often as refactoring would be to much of work.

Answer (score 1):

Make your singleton `class` a `template`.

```
template<unsigned int NUMBER>
class Foo
{
  A* a;
  B* b;
  C* c;
};
```

And use whatever few instances you want. It will still remain singleton, but you can have multiple objects:

```
Foo<1>;
Foo<2>;
Foo<3>;
```

Comment: Yep, I understand this, but when I am in A, B, or C class, I do not know in which one of the Foo's instance has me as member.

Comment: @ptrdiff_t, you may have to fine tune your code accordingly. My suggestion is just an idea to use templates; larger picture will be better known by you than me. :)

Answer (score 0):

I've done this in a few projects. Here's some pseudo-code to give you an idea of how I accomplished it:

```
static map<string, Foo*> instances;

static Foo* Foo::getInstance(string name)
{
    Foo* inst = NULL;

    lock(instances);
    if(instances.count(name) > 0)
    {
        inst = instances[name];
    }
    else
    {
        inst = new Foo();
        instances[name] = inst;
    }

    unlock(instances);
    return inst;
}
```

Then you just call Foo::getInstance("instance1") or Foo::getInstance("instance2"), etc. All you have to do is remember a string, kinda nice (I think). I don't know if there's a formal name for this design pattern, if there is someone please tell me so I don't sound so ignorant in the future when describing this.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about this kind of implementation too but there's no way the A, B, C's to know which instance has initialized them :)

Comment: OK, I see what you're saying, however by that point no matter what solution you come up with you're going to have to tell A, B, and C *something* about their creator, which violates your initial constraints. I don't believe there's any answer to this.

Comment: Yep, that's something I was afraid of. Just making sure if there's any way to do it easily. I am so in love with the pattern..

Comment: An object knowing about its creator without explicitly being told simply isn't possible. The way you're doing it right now is kind of cheating as it is, you're more or less saying "assume that this specific instance is your creator". You might possibly explore the factory pattern, that MIGHT do it for you depending on your needs, however no matter how you cut it they'll need to be explicitly told.

Answer (score 0):

Singletons are evil, we all agree.  But the reason why is often forgotten.  It's not because they're essentially a global.  Globals are great when they solve the problem.  Singletons are problematic in that they couple lifetime, initialization order, and global access.

It sounds like you need a global, so use a global.

```
A* g_a;
B* g_b;
C* g_c;
```

Initialize all globals in main before anything else needs to access them.

Or do it smarter.

```
template< typename T >
T& instance( void );

template< typename T >
void set_instance( T& t );

void needs_an_A( void )
{
   instance<A>().a_stuff();
}
```

Or best of all tie it all in with RAII:

```
void needs_a_b( void )
{
   B& b = instance<B>();
   b.stuff();
   b.more_stuff();
}

int main()
{
   Initializer<A> init_a;
   Initializer<B> init_b;  // B needs an A during construction
   Initializer<C> init_c( "C constructor param" );

   needs_a_b();
}
```